# Credit card Processing Dillemma

Tags: magento-1.9, store-credit, pci

We have a card processing machine, in house.. However I am looking for a third party PCI compliant encrypted Company to save the credit card information, instead of our backend, for security purposes, and I would just feel more secure having the credit card information separate. Is this a good solution? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Speak to your current processor, they most definitely have an online solution. You would only need to either hire a developer or if they are popular enough there is probably a 3rd party module available that will integrate with Magento.

We personally do not store any client credit card numbers, only partial and expiry dates.

Answer (score 0):

Your top choice would be either

1. [Autorize.net CIM](http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/cim/)
2. [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/)

They both store the customer credit card information on there server and the only thing that you need to store is "token" that refer to the customer billing information and/or there credit card profile.